# Getting manager of manager of an employee

Tags: mysql, schema, query-optimization

I have an employee table which contains a manager ID as a column. If I need to get the manager of manager of a certain employee, how would I do it efficiently? How about if we are required to a 5 layers deep?

If this a requirement can we change the database schema so that this could be done more efficienty?

Comment: Can you dynamically create the query to determine how many up you need to go?

Comment: What does your current schema for this look like, relating manager to employee?

Comment: Does an employee only have one manager, or do you support matrixed employees?

Comment: I'm puzzled why this got a downvote.

Comment: say we have an employee table which has a manager ID as a column.....so the same table contains employees and their managers.....also this is a question that I was asked by an interviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/) to see how you can define your own version of Oracle's `connect by` customization.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm doing something like this I would probably just have people in table
`employee`

Then I'd have a table `management` with columns
`manager_id` and `employee_id`

Both columns are referencing employee.id (because a manager is an employee too, get it?)

That way you can just create a `management` entry for each employee that points to his manager, and do the same for each manager, etc... and it will go as many levels deep as you need.

Edit: Really I would assume you would have another table `managerdata` with additional data about each manager, but I wouldn't duplicate data that's in `employee` - just add the extra details about the manager and include a column pointing to `employee.id`

Comment: A good idea, I'm scared away because of the exponential growth (add one employee, need to update everyone's link to that employee/manager); but it would be faster if he is making this query a lot.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. If you add an employee you would only have to insert them as an employee and then add a single row for their manager and any people directly under them. For example the president would not have a link to the janitor, only to the people directly below him (VPs, etc).

Comment: Oh, I misread your post.  It sounded like you would build a row to each and every other person in the company explaining their position relative to the inserted employee.  Instead of only the employees directly above and below.

Comment: I see how it could sound like that and yeah that wouldn't be ideal. My goal with the database is to allow for storing the least amount of data possible that can tell the whole story. If I want to see complicated things about the data that's what clever queries and smart scripting are for.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to just recurse up as far as you need.  A simple example would be:

```
///hight: how far up the manager chain to go
///startid: The id from which to start
function getManager ($startid, $hight)
{
    return getManagerRecurse ($hight, 0, $startid);
}
function getManagerRecurse ($hight, $curHight, $curid)
{
    if ($hight == $curHight)
        return $curid;
    $sql = "SELECT `managerid` FROM `table` WHERE `id`='$curid' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        return -1; //Can't go up any further, so just return -1
    list($manid) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return getManagerRecurse ($hight, $curHight + 1, $manid);
}


getManager (15,2); //Start at id 15, go up 2 managers
```

Note: not tested